# Why is easelJS scaling my sprites?

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite, easeljs, createjs

I am creating an animated background in Canvas with EaselJS. I am wondering why my sprites are being scaled as soon as I set my canvas to the size of the window... 
The images are looking streched...

> $('body').append('');
>   $('#backgroundCanvas').height($(window).height());
>   $('#backgroundCanvas').width($(window).width());

---

```
var sprite = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
          "animations":
            {
                "run": [0, 6, "run", frequency]},
                "images": [url],
                "frames":
                    {
                        "height": height,
                        "width":width,
                        "regX": 0,
                        "regY": 0,
                        "count": count
                    }
            });
                    var item = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(sprite);    
                    item.height = height;       
                    item.width = width;             
                    //item.scale = item.scaleY = item.scaleX= 0.5;  
                    item.x = positionX;         
                    item.y = positionY;
                    item.dirX = 1;  
                    item.dirY = 1;      
                    item.vX = 4;            
                    item.vY = 4;


                    item.gotoAndPlay("run");

                    stage.addChild(item);
```

Comment: Can you post your code or a link to your issue?

Comment: Is your original canvas sized proportionally to the window?

Answer (score 3):

When you scale a canvas with CSS, it will scale the contents, since its the same number of pixels. Scale it with JavaScript (set the width and height properties), and it changes the amount of pixels, and will not stretch your content.

Cheers.

Comment: jQuery width() and height() methods will use CSS to set the size, not JavaScript. You need to target the canvas directly, and use JavaScript to set the width/height. @fareed posted a solution using jQuery in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

it important to know that the canvas object get its width and height from the html attr width and height changing the width and height for css will only scale the canvas object

so you have 2 solutions:
use this html

```
<canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="968" height="358"></canvas>
```

or change your code to:

```
$('#backgroundCanvas').attr("height",$(window).height());
$('#backgroundCanvas').attr("width",$(window).width());
```

now i can tell you cheers ;)